# Redis cluster bus port connections does not have keepalive on it

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-3.2

We have a not so stable network in our production, so there are a lot of failovers happening. One thing we noticed is that there are 3k tcp connections to 1 machine cluster bus port (using the example from documentation, that would be 16379). This is happening for all redis nodes on this machine.

When we execute netstat with display timers options, we can see that keepalive is off.

```
sudo netstat -anpo | grep :165 | grep -v LISTEN

tcp  10.10.111.122:16379  10.10.111.121:41227  ESTABLISHED 2571/redis-server 1 off (0.00/0/0)
...
```

The thing is, we can see these connections only on machine where redis server node is, but these connections should be closed (we can see them only from one machine, but not from the other)

We are using redis version 3.2.8 where tcp-keepalive (set to 300) is enabled by default and we can see it is working for listening port for clients

```
tcp  10.10.111.122:6379  10.10.111.121:50461  ESTABLISHED 2571/redis-server  keepalive (103.28/0/0)
```

Why isn't it working for cluster bus ports?

**UPDATE**: I have opened [an issue in Redis GitHub to ask about this too](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/5876).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use libkeepalive:library preloading

It consists of a shared library that overrides the socket system called in most binaries, without the need to recompile or modify them. The technique is based on the preloading feature of the ld.so(8) loader included in Linux, which allows you to force the loading of shared libraries with higher priority than normal.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libkeepalive.so KEEPCNT=20 KEEPIDLE=180 KEEPINTVL=60 /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf

$ netstat -ton | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 17000

tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:41046 10.143.4.87:17000 ESTABLISHED keepalive (166.82/0/0)
tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:17000 10.143.4.89:44282 ESTABLISHED keepalive (166.82/0/0)
tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:17000 10.143.4.89:44284 ESTABLISHED keepalive (162.73/0/0)
tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:35134 10.143.4.89:17000 ESTABLISHED keepalive (162.73/0/0)
tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:37218 10.143.4.87:17000 ESTABLISHED keepalive (164.78/0/0)
tcp 0 0 10.143.4.86:17000 10.143.4.87:47532 ESTABLISHED keepalive (169.38/0/0)
```

Please refer to the following link for implementation.

https://medium.com/@rajivsharma.2205/enable-tcp-keepalive-on-redis-cluster-bus-153128e412fa